# How to get access to the initial blank white block and change its style when iframe preload is false?

Tags: fancybox, fancybox-2, fancybox-3

I am using Fancybox 3 for my project. Here is my code

```
modal: true,
iframe: {
    css: {
        width : '900px',
        height: 'auto'
    },
    preload: false 
}
```

When the fancybox starts to show, it first shows a blank white block. This white block stays half a second or one or two seconds depnding on the content. Please see this screenshot:

[image]

I would like to access it and do some customization. How can I get access to it? How to change its style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you want to customize. This is how, for example, you can make background transparent:

```
.fancybox-slide--iframe .fancybox-content,
.fancybox-iframe {
  background: transparent;
}
```

This is how you can append, for example, loading icon:

```
$('[data-fancybox]').fancybox({
  iframe : {
    preload : false
  },
  afterLoad : function(instance, slide) {
    slide.mySpinner = $( instance.opts.spinnerTpl ).appendTo( slide.$slide )
  },
  afterShow : function(instance, slide) {
    slide.mySpinner.remove();
  }
});
```

Demo - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rzORYL

Comment: Janis: I hope to MANUALLY show the loading spinning wheel the moment wehn the white blank block is supposed to show (now it is transparent, which is good) Should I add `instance.showLoading( slide );` in an event? Which event? Is this doable? I tested different events, but not able to see the spinning wheel.

Comment: I updated answer with new snippet. You just have to decide when to hide it.

Comment: Janis, just wanted to let you know. It seems that the display of spinning wheel in Fancybox 3 is not centered vertically or horizontally. It is based on my test of iframe.

Comment: It is created and centered using CSS only.